# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." When Creating a new user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am attempting to create a new user in my platform when they sign up for my app. I want them to enter their details and send it up to the server to create the account so they can sign in and then receive a token. Whenever I use postman to send up the credentials I get this error:

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

This is what I have so far:

**Settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'buddysapp',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
    'bootstrap3',
    'multiselectfield',
    'openinghours',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'import_export',
    'phone_field',
    'django_s3_storage',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',



    ),
}
REST_USE_JWT = True



def jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(user):

    return {
        'username': user.username,
        'email': user.email
    }


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    # 'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
}
```

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def createApp_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = AppSignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user=serializer.save()
            data['response']= 'Successfully registered new user.'
            data['email'] = user.email
            data['username'] = user.username
        # else:
            # data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class AppSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'password': True}}
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    username = serializers.CharField(
            max_length=32,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=100,
            write_only=True)

    def save(self):
        user = User(
        first_name=self.validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'],
        email=self.validated_data['email'],
        username=self.validated_data['username']

        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ***global DRF settings is applied to the `createApp_user`*** view also.
What you have to do is, provide empty `permission_classes` and `authentication_classes` settings to your view by corresponding decorators, as below

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes


@api_view(['POST', ])
@authentication_classes(())
@permission_classes(())
def createApp_user(request):
    ...
    # your rest of the code
```